# php numeric array select values greater than a number and lower than another and save it to a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have one array(dynamically created) that contains the following numbers

```
$numbers = array (200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 12000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 18000, 20000, 21000, 24000, 25000, 27000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 75000, 80000, 90000, 100000, 105000, 120000, 135000, 140000, 150000, 160000, 180000, 200000, 250000, 300000, 350000, 400000, 450000, 500000, 600000, 700000, 800000, 900000, 1000000)
```

I want to create new array (filtered) by >= and <= for example the new array to contains numbers greater or equal(>=) than 800 and lower or equal(<=) than 1600

```
New Array
(
    [0] => 800
    [1] => 1000
    [2] => 1200
    [3] => 1400
    [4] => 1600
)
```

is that possible without using foreach?

Comment: array_filter() with a callback

Comment: ^ `array_filter($numbers, function($n){ return $n >= 800 && $n <= 1600 }`

Comment: yes! I did not know it how to pass two variables to array_filter. thanks both of you!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$min = 800;
$max = 1200;
$newNumbers = array_filter(
    $numbers,
    function ($value) use($min,$max) {
        return ($value >= $min && $value <= $max);
    }
);
```

Comment: @CJDennis - the significant difference is that "use" variable values (`$min` and `$max`) are fixed (and so must exist) at the point where the anonymous/lambda function is defined, whereas normal arguments (in this case `$value`) are passed when the function is called.... it doesn't make much difference in this case, but may in other cases

Comment: The other difference is that the callback for array_filter() accepts only a specific argument or argument set (you can pass the key as well in recent versions of PHP), so you need to use `use` in that case  to pass additional arguments to the function

Comment: I've been wondering how to pass extra variables to lambda functions and now I know!

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

A good example of use would be:

```
array_filter($numbers, function($n){ 
    return $n >= 800 && $n <= 1600;
});
```