# Filter a 2d array and retain rows where a column value falls within a qualifying numeric range

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, numeric

I can't figure out how to get the desired values. I am trying to filter my array on it's values.

```
#current array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product1 
            [1] => Description product 1
            [2] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product2
            [1] => Description product 2
            [2] => 20       
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product3
            [1] => Description product 3  
            [2] => 30    
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product4
            [1] => Description product 4  
            [2] => 40    
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product5
            [1] => Description product 5  
            [2] => 50    
        )
)

#resultant array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product3 
            [1] => Description product 3
            [2] => 30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Product4
            [1] => Description product 4
            [2] => 40       
        )
)
```

As you can see in my block of code, I am trying to create a new array filtered by >= and <=. For example the `#resultant array` only contains records where [2] is bigger (>=) than 30 and lower or equal (<=) than 40.

I did find an answer for a non-dimensional array, but I can't figure out how to use it for my application see: [php numeric array select values greater than a number and lower than another and save it to a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776113/php-numeric-array-select-values-greater-than-a-number-and-lower-than-another-and)

I just can't figure out how to write/build this code, I also would like two variables; $min = 30 and $max = 40 for example.

Comment: Please show the code that you've tried.

Comment: You can iterate over your array elements and filter using the criteria you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter your array based on conditions:

```
<?php
    $data = array
    (
        0 => array
        (
            0 => 'Product1',
            1 => 'Description product 1',
            2 => '10'
        ),
        1 => array
        (
            0 => 'Product2',
            1 => 'Description product 2',
            2 => '20'
        ),
        2 => array
        (
            0 => 'Product3',
            1 => 'Description product 3',
            2 => '30'
        ),
        3 => array
        (
            0 => 'Product4',
            1 => 'Description product 4',
            2 => '40'
        ),
        4 => array
        (
            0 => 'Product5',
            1 => 'Description product 5',
            2 => '50'
        )
    );

    $data = array_filter($data, function($el)
    {
        return ($el[2] >= 30 && $el[2] <= 40);
    });

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($data, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Here you can just pass a function into the second callback and set your conditions that way.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me a lot! Do you know perhaps know how to skip the first array with product 1 in it, So it will stay? Cheers

Comment: @Cody what do you mean? Do you want to keep the first array in tact? Just store the results in a new var?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use foreach and if condition check code bellow :

```
$array=Array();
$array[]=array('Product1','Description product 1',10);
$array[]=array('Product2','Description product 2',20);
$array[]=array('Product3','Description product 3',30);
$array[]=array('Product4','Description product 4',40);
$array[]=array('Product5','Description product 5',50);

// code
$array2=array();
foreach($array as $row)
{

    if($row[2] >=30 and $row[2] <=40)
        $array2[]=$row;


}

#resultant array
print_r($array2);

die;
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
$array = [
  0 => "item1",
];
```

To target the string "item1" you can call the first item in the array by with

```
echo $array[0];
```

And to use multidimensional arrays you can for example do this

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        0 => 'item1',
        1 => 'item2',
    ]
    1 => [
        0 => 'item3',
        1 => 'item4',
    ]
]
```

To target for example the string "item3" you can use this

```
$array[1][0];
```

Here you target the first item in the second array inside `$array`